# document.form.submit(); won't submit in safari

Tags: javascript, forms, safari, submit

I'm using a javascript function to submit my form.  This works in every browser except safari and I can't figure out why

My javascript function looks like this

```
function submitForm() { 
    var selectBox = '';
    sel_guide_options = document.subForm.sel_guides;

    if (sel_guide_options.type == "select-multiple") {
         for (var i = 0; i <sel_guide_options.options.length; i++) {
              sel_guide_options.options[i].selected = true;
         }
    } 

    document.subForm.submit();
}
```

and in my form I use this

```
<input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="#modification_type# #page_item#" id="btnSubmit" onclick="submitForm();">
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Firefox handles xxx.submit(), Safari doesn't ... what can be done?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333329/firefox-handles-xxx-submit-safari-doesnt-what-can-be-done)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/333329/firefox-handles-xxx-submit-safari-doesnt-what-can-be-done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the form element from a type="submit" to type="button". 
Both should work but it's worth a try.

Comment: If you take everything out of the function except the submit() call, does it still not submit?

Comment: Nope, it still won't submit with nothing in the function except the submit() call

Comment: I seemed to have fixed it using
document.subForm['0'].submit();
instead of 
document.subForm.submit();

No idea why that would make a difference but its not giving me any problems now.  Works on the other browsers too.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

does `document.subForm.sel_guides` point to a select list?

if so I would revise your code to (presuming `subForm` is the `name` of your form):

```
function submitForm() { 
    var selectBox = '';
    var sForm = document.forms['subForm'];
    sel_guide = sForm.elements['sel_guides'];

    if (sel_guide.type == "select-multiple") {
         for (var i = 0; i <sel_guide.options.length; i++) {
              sel_guide.options[i].selected = true;
         }
    } 
    sForm.submit();
}
```

Comment: This didn't really work with the select list, but thanks for the help!

Comment: What does the HTML look like for your select list? If you can provide it, I'm sure I can solve this for you.

Answer (score 1):

I seemed to have fixed it using document.subForm['0'].submit(); 
instead of document.subForm.submit(); 
No idea why that would make a difference but its not giving me any problems now. Works on the other browsers too.